# Timestamp information of MP4

Tags: video, ffmpeg, eye-tracking

I want to ask for an easy way to get the timestamp information of a mp4 file. (Sorry that I am not familiar with codec.)

I am reading the Tobii Pro Glasses SDK document that explains how to synchronize frame with eye tracking data, where they use a terminorlogy called VTS. Goolge cannot find the exact meaning, so I want to ask for what VTS really stands for and how to get it from a mp4 file. Thanks very much!

Comment: Try the mp4v2 library.

Comment: This is worth having a look at if you need to understand time stamps in video as it is a little (!) tricky: http://dranger.com/ffmpeg/tutorial05.html

Comment: Great resources! Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `ffprobe.exe` as follows:

```
ffprobe -i 396025.MP4 -show_packets
```

Refer to https://www.ffmpeg.org/ffprobe.html

Comment: Thanks. I can see the packets. But I did not find the so-called vts-time information. Do you know what vts-time stands for? And also TLSV?

Comment: I hoped VTS stands for "Video Time Stamp", but I think it's an internal term used by Tobii Pro Glasses SDK.  Sorry, but I can't find it eater.

Comment: Yes. Thanks anyway. The SDK document is kind of vague.

Comment: In Tobii Glasses SDK vts packages in data stream basically define a map points between glasses internal clock (which is used to timestamp gaze data and data from any other stream) and video file samples time. So whenever you have entry with zero vts value, it's timestamp defines where vide file starts in relation to